# How many roots has the equation?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$. How many roots has the equation: $f(f(x))=0$?

I tried to solve it graphically and found 7 roots. If there exists analytical solution?

Comment: $f(f(x))$ seems to be of degree $9$, So how many roots can it have?

Comment: 9 complex ones according to the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Seems I found real roots only.

Comment: Depends on the context. You can use the FTA for an analytical solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Find the solutions of $f(x) = 0$. Than can be done with the Cardano method. If $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$ are those solutions then use the same method to solve the equations:

$$\begin{cases}f(x) = z_1 \\ f(x) = z_2 \\ f(x) = z_3 \end{cases}$$

Those nine solutions will be the solutions of $f(f(x)) = 0$

Comment: Of course, it takes some care to assert that they are nine distinct solutions.

Comment: Oh, by all means some could be the same one. This is just a way to find them with algebra.

Comment: Check the question - it is not to find them....

Comment: Well, yes, but if you find them you know how many there are.

Comment: Except that you have to check pretty complicated expressions to find if they are equal. (It is often hard to check the results you get from Cardano even to check if they are real...)

Answer (score 1):

We can easily see that there are three real roots to $f(x)$ since $f(-2)=-1$ and $f(-1)=3$, $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=3$.

Now, for each of the three roots of $f(x)$,  $r_1,r_2,r_3$, with $-2<r_1<-1<r_2<1<r_3<2$, we want solutions to $f(x)=r_i$. There are always three distinct roots to this equation, since $1,-1$, the roots of $f'(x)$, are not roots of $f(x)-r_i$, since that value is not an integer for $x$ an integer, and thus specifically is never zero when $x$ is an integer.

So there are nine distinct roots, some potentially complex.

Now, the local maximum and minimum of $f(x)$ are at $x=-1$ and $x=1$, respectively, with values $f(-1)=3$ and $f(1)=-1$. So there are three real roots for $-1<r_i<3, i=2,3$, and only one real root for the $r_1$ outside of that range. So there are 7 real roots, and two complex roots.